# Is it possible to provide a google pay scratch card for using your app?

Tags: google-api-client, google-pay, scratchcard

Suppose I created an App, and every time the user completes an action on my app, they get a scratch card (but in google pay). Is such a support provided by google pay?

Comment: Which region is this for? Is this for India?

Comment: Yes, for India region. Is this feature supported elsewhere?

Comment: Yes @Soc for india region